# Build tree from xml

Tags: xml, tree

I want to build a graphical representation of an xml file because a client of mine requested a simplified view of the xml that is going to be used.

I have found a couple of online tools that parse xml files to produce treeview representations (codebeautify and xmlgrid) but they don't suit my needs because i need to save the output but that option is not offered.

Is there any tool that converts xml files to trees?

Are there any programming solutions available ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**yED Graph Editor**](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html).
After, open *yED Graph Editor*, New Document-->Drag and Drop XML File (XSL File for: Select **XML-Tree**-->OK).

**Example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<EVENT>
  <SUBEVENT>
    <PLACE>London</PLACE>
    <NAME>Title</NAME>
    <PERIOD>Insert Date</PERIOD>
  </SUBEVENT>

       <SUBEVENT>
    <PLACE>London</PLACE>
    <NAME>Title</NAME>
    <PERIOD>Insert Date</PERIOD>
  </SUBEVENT>

          <SUBEVENT>
    <PLACE>London</PLACE>
    <NAME>Title</NAME>
    <PERIOD>Insert Date</PERIOD>
  </SUBEVENT>

           <SUBEVENT>
    <PLACE>London</PLACE>
    <NAME>Title</NAME>
    <PERIOD>Insert Date</PERIOD>
  </SUBEVENT>

         <SUBEVENT>
    <PLACE>London</PLACE>
    <NAME>Title</NAME>
    <PERIOD>Insert Date</PERIOD>
  </SUBEVENT>

           <SUBEVENT>
    <PLACE>London</PLACE>
    <NAME>Title</NAME>
    <PERIOD>Insert Date</PERIOD>
  </SUBEVENT>

           <SUBEVENT>
    <PLACE>London</PLACE>
    <NAME>Title</NAME>
    <PERIOD>Insert Date</PERIOD>
  </SUBEVENT>
</EVENT>
```

Comment: Test my example, and drag and drop this in yED.

Comment: Same as with mine...I can see only the elements,not the text included. Is there any option i should check ? I don't see anything relevant